# How to have multiple threads work on the same graph?

Tags: multithreading, graph-theory

So I'm trying to create a very large Minesweeper game, and I was going to have the whole map be stored in a container, probably a 2D array. In Minesweeper, when you reveal a blank tile, all 8 adjacent tiles are revealed, and if one of those are a blank tile, then *its* neighbors are revealed, and so the whole thing is recursive.

For a very large map, this can easily escalate so that it takes way too long for the whole algorithm to finish. I want to use threads to reveal the tiles in parallel, but if all threads are accessing the same graph, then I'll have to use locks. Pretty much every thread will just sit there waiting for their turn to access the map when really I want it to be done in parallel.

My question is, how do you multithread algorithms that access a graph e.g. BFS? Do you partition the graph and then have one thread per partition? Or do you just go ahead and use locks? I'm really interested in the general theory so if anyone has links to any good reading material I'd love to take a look at those too (hopefully I can understand it though!).

Comment: instead of locking acces to the entire board, you can lock acces to a single cell, by having an array of mutex equivalent of the game board.

Comment: @proton Are mutexes expensive objects? I'm aiming for 1000x1000 minesweeper, so I'm trying to minimize the memory footprint haha

Comment: I dont know. another option is to use atomic operations.

Comment: Mutexes are expensive indeed. I don't believe a matrix of size 1000x1000 would justify using parallel algorithms, it is not that big. Nevertheless, I imagine you would use a shared queue of vertices and each thread would get the next vertex and work its way. You can use atomic operations to mark a vertex being visited. In this approach, mutexes are needed for synching access to the shared queue.

Comment: Well with the shared queue, how would I prevent duplicate visits? For each cell I queue its adjacent neighbors, and theres going to be a lot of overlap. I could check whether each cell has already been visited before queueing it, but then I might encounter race conditions.